# How to correctly link the path of external library in CMake?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cmake, cmake-language, cmake-format

In the CMakeLists.txt, if I define the .lib (static library) file path as absolute path, it's working correctly. But if I define the same as relative path, an error is thrown. How do I solve it without hard coded ?

File structure:

```
|--D
|  |--Rohit
|  |  |--Sandbox
|  |  |  |--demo
|  |  |  |  |--src
|  |  |  |  |  |--abc
|  |  |  |  |  |  |--build
|  |  |  |  |  |  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |  |  |  |  |  |--lib
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--foo.lib
.
.
|  |  |  |  |--workspace
|  |  |  |  |  |--xyz
|  |  |  |  |  |  |--foo2.lib
```

This way is working fine:

```
add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION D:/Rohit/Sandbox/demo/src/abc/lib/foo.lib)
```

This way is throwing error:

```
add_library(foo STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/lib/foo.lib")
```

My CMakeLists.txt path: **D:\Rohit\Sandbox\demo\src\abc\CmakeLists.txt**

This is error I'm getting: **LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '\lib\foo.lib'**

Also if I want to include .lib file from some other folder (let's say foo2.lib file is present in xyz folder of workspace), How to define it ?

Comment: adding library is different than linking it, do ldconfig and lib path to ldconfig, or in echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH , the lib dir must be found.

Comment: Solved it using: `set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/foo.lib)`